# Is it safe to type password when scripting commands via ssh?

Tags: security, ssh

I've seen this handy command to query a distant database from my local machine:

```
ssh user@server 'mysql -uimauser -pPassWord imadb -e "select * from table"'
```

But I wonder how safe it is?
Can anyone capture the password? If so how?

I'm aware that this works well too:

```
ssh user@server 'mysql -uimauser -p imadb -e "select * from table"'
```

But for automation purpose, I would prefer the first solution (if safe of course).
I've tried to capture the password with ps but I didn't see anything (my knowledge of ps is also very poor).

Comment: ssh means secure shell,so...

Comment: The command _will_ be visible in the remote process table, but only until it has finished. So the duration depends on how long that statement takes. But certainly it means that approach is _not_ safe. Some user on the remote system will be able to spot it.

Comment: @machine_1 With that way of reasoning one could also think that MS-Windows is safe, MS says so.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. Do you know which commands I should type to see the remote process table?

Comment: `ps aux|grep mysql`, but as said: it will valish as soon as the select has finished, since the process then terminates. Depending on your table content this will be after a milisecond or 20 minutes.

Comment: @arkascha I was able to catch it! However, the password appears with two x (mysql -uroot -px xx). Is there a way to access the real password? If not, and if ps is the only tool for that case, I would consider it okay, wouldn't you?

Comment: You have to decide for yourself what is OK for you and what not. I myself would always go with the interactive way to specify a password (which can also be automated).

Comment: I never heard that some version of a `ps` utility obfuscates passwords. But ok, if you say so... But keep in mind that there are other tools to access the same information.

Comment: You will get the password stored in bash history, if you don't forbid it explicitly. This is probably the worst issue, since it will get written on the hard drive.

Comment: Actually, I tested that but although I could see the sql request with ps aux, it didn't get caught in the history (using a default debian 8 virtual machine). So from my tests at least, it seems that the history don't catch the command passed via ssh. I hope someone can prove me wrong.